# how to specify xml element having a xml attribute

Tags: c#, xml

What should be the class structure such that it serializes in the format given below

```
 <Header>
          <Version environment="debug">2.2</Version>
 </Header>
```

```
[XmlRoot]
public class Header
{
   [XmlElement]
   public string Version{get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[XmlRoot]
public class Header
{
    [XmlElement]
    public Version Version { get; set; }
}

public class Version
{
    [XmlAttribute("environment")]
    public String Environment { get; set; }

    [XmlText]
    public String Value { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Oh..i was just not able to find this..Thank you :)